# jQuery UI Autocomplete to expand from right to left

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to get the `div.ui-autocomplete` to expand from right to left, this is the problem I'm having right now.

Can this be fixed using CSS or is there a way to do that with jQuery?

[image: auto complete]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you can do that with the **position** option of the autocomplete widget

```js
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    position: {
        my : "right top",
        at: "right bottom"
    }
});
```